# SQL Inserting in to an external table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am looking to insert data into a different table that users are using.

I think I am on the right track to piecing this together but looks like ill need a hand

**My Code:**

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [MS Access;pwd=" & strPassword & ";database=" & DBpath & "\" & DBname & "].[" & tblengagement & "]" _
        & "(CDP,Open_Date, Open_Time) VALUES " _
        & "'" & Environ("UserName") & "', Date(), Time());"
```

**Error**
Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

**What I am trying to achieve**
When a user opens the database I want to send the username, date, time to a database stored in a different location

**UPDATE**

I have broken the code down and got the below working, just need to work out how to get date, time in there:

```
CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO [MS Access;pwd=" & strPassword & ";database=" & DBpath & "\" & DBname & "].[" & tblengagement & "] " _
        & "(CDP) VALUES " _
        & "('" & Environ("UserName") & "');"
```

Comment: Like your [Update question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280597/access-sql-update-record), why are you making an external database call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date()` and `time()` are functions and should not be within the quotation string. Dates and Times need to be enclosed by `#` signs.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [MS Access;pwd=" & strPassword & ";database=" & DBpath & "\" & DBname & "].[" & tblengagement & "]" _
    & "(CDP,Open_Date, Open_Time) VALUES " _
    & "'" & Environ("UserName") & "',#" & Date() & "#,#" & Time() & "#);"
```