# Access SQL Update record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to update an existing record in a table.

I have been trying two different methods but can't see what I am missing:

**First attempt was:**

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [MS Access;pwd=" & strPassword & ";database=" & DBpath & "\" & DBname & "].[" & tblengagement & "] SET [Close_Time] = #" & Time & "#, WHERE ID = '" & SessionID & "'"
```

**Second attempt:**

```
CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE [MS Access;pwd=" & strPassword & ";database=" & DBpath & "\" & DBname & "].[" & tblengagement & "] " _
        & "(Close_Time) VALUES " _
        & "(#" & Time & "#)" _
'        & "WHERE ID = '" & SessionID & "';"
```

**Error Received:**
Syntax error

**UPDATE OF MY CODE:**

```
Dim strPassword As String
Dim DBpath As String
Dim DBname As String
Dim tblengagement As String

DBpath = "C:\Projects"
DBname = "Data.accdb"
strPassword = "1234"

tblengagement = "tbl_engagement"

'CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE [MS Access;pwd=" & strPassword & ";database=" & DBpath & "\" & DBname & "].[" & tblengagement & "] " _
'        & "(Close_Time) VALUES " _
'        & "(#" & Time & "#)" _
'        & "WHERE ID = '" & SessionID & "';"
```

Comment: Store the constructed statement in a string variable first, then print it out or examine it. Post it here and it will be easier to see a syntax error (you can still disguise password, etc.). You are also using numerous variables and we have no idea how these are formed.

Comment: Please see my updated code - This is very much knew to me im afraid

Comment: Why is the Execute call commented out?

Comment: It was commented out because it was toggling between the two codes I was working with

Comment: Why would you comment out the code that reproduces the error you want us to fix?

Comment: It wasn't commented out when I was using it, I commented it our to try the first attempt code I mentioned

Comment: Are you updating an external database or current one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct code:**

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [MS Access;pwd=" & strPassword & ";database=" & DBpath & "\" & DBname & "].[" & tblengagement & "] " _
              & "SET [Close_Time] = #" & Time & "# WHERE ID = '" & SessionID & "';"
```

**What the problem was:**
I had left a **,** in my code, once removed it worked fine